# How can I get current user or user-id in my soft-delete-component's SoftCrudRepository method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, loopback

I'm working on [loopback4-soft-delete](https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-soft-delete) component. I need to add `deletedBy` field to *SoftDeleteEntity* model. `deletedBy` should be propagated with the current logged-in user.

Can someone tell me, how can I get current user or user-id in my soft-delete-component's `SoftCrudRepository` method?

Here is my model:

```
export abstract class SoftDeleteEntity extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'boolean',
    default: false,
  })
  deleted?: boolean;

  @property({
    type: 'date',
    name: 'deleted_on',
  })
  deletedOn: Date;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    name: 'deleted_by',
  })
  deletedBy: number;

  constructor(data?: Partial<SoftDeleteEntity>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

Here is my repository:

```
export abstract class SoftCrudRepository<
  T extends SoftDeleteEntity,
  ID,
  Relations extends object = {}
> extends DefaultCrudRepository<T, ID, Relations> {
  constructor(
    entityClass: typeof SoftDeleteEntity & {
      prototype: T;
    },
    dataSource: juggler.DataSource,
  ) {
    super(entityClass, dataSource);
  }

  find(filter?: Filter<T>, options?: Options): Promise<(T & Relations)[]> {
    // Filter out soft deleted entries
    if (
      filter?.where &&
      (filter.where as AndClause<T>).and &&
      (filter.where as AndClause<T>).and.length > 0
    ) {
      (filter.where as AndClause<T>).and.push({
        deleted: false,
      } as Condition<T>);
    } else if (
      filter?.where &&
      (filter.where as OrClause<T>).or &&
      (filter.where as OrClause<T>).or.length > 0
    ) {
      filter = {
        where: {
          and: [
            {
              deleted: false,
            } as Condition<T>,
            {
              or: (filter.where as OrClause<T>).or,
            },
          ],
        },
      };
    } else {
      filter = filter ?? {};
      filter.where = filter.where ?? {};
      (filter.where as Condition<T>).deleted = false;
    }

    // Now call super
    return super.find(filter, options);
  }

  findOne(
    filter?: Filter<T>,
    options?: Options,
  ): Promise<(T & Relations) | null> {
    // Filter out soft deleted entries
    if (
      filter?.where &&
      (filter.where as AndClause<T>).and &&
      (filter.where as AndClause<T>).and.length > 0
    ) {
      (filter.where as AndClause<T>).and.push({
        deleted: false,
      } as Condition<T>);
    } else if (
      filter?.where &&
      (filter.where as OrClause<T>).or &&
      (filter.where as OrClause<T>).or.length > 0
    ) {
      filter = {
        where: {
          and: [
            {
              deleted: false,
            } as Condition<T>,
            {
              or: (filter.where as OrClause<T>).or,
            },
          ],
        },
      };
    } else {
      filter = filter ?? {};
      filter.where = filter.where ?? {};
      (filter.where as Condition<T>).deleted = false;
    }

    // Now call super
    return super.findOne(filter, options);
  }

  findById(
    id: ID,
    filter?: Filter<T>,
    options?: Options,
  ): Promise<T & Relations> {
    // Filter out soft deleted entries
    if (
      filter?.where &&
      (filter.where as AndClause<T>).and &&
      (filter.where as AndClause<T>).and.length > 0
    ) {
      (filter.where as AndClause<T>).and.push({
        deleted: false,
      } as Condition<T>);
    } else if (
      filter?.where &&
      (filter.where as OrClause<T>).or &&
      (filter.where as OrClause<T>).or.length > 0
    ) {
      filter = {
        where: {
          and: [
            {
              deleted: false,
            } as Condition<T>,
            {
              or: (filter.where as OrClause<T>).or,
            },
          ],
        },
      };
    } else {
      filter = filter ?? {};
      filter.where = filter.where ?? {};
      (filter.where as Condition<T>).deleted = false;
    }

    // Now call super
    return super.findById(id, filter, options);
  }

  updateAll(
    data: DataObject<T>,
    where?: Where<T>,
    options?: Options,
  ): Promise<Count> {
    // Filter out soft deleted entries
    if (
      where &&
      (where as AndClause<T>).and &&
      (where as AndClause<T>).and.length > 0
    ) {
      (where as AndClause<T>).and.push({
        deleted: false,
      } as Condition<T>);
    } else if (
      where &&
      (where as OrClause<T>).or &&
      (where as OrClause<T>).or.length > 0
    ) {
      where = {
        and: [
          {
            deleted: false,
          } as Condition<T>,
          {
            or: (where as OrClause<T>).or,
          },
        ],
      };
    } else {
      where = where ?? {};
      (where as Condition<T>).deleted = false;
    }

    // Now call super
    return super.updateAll(data, where, options);
  }

  count(where?: Where<T>, options?: Options): Promise<Count> {
    // Filter out soft deleted entries
    if (
      where &&
      (where as AndClause<T>).and &&
      (where as AndClause<T>).and.length > 0
    ) {
      (where as AndClause<T>).and.push({
        deleted: false,
      } as Condition<T>);
    } else if (
      where &&
      (where as OrClause<T>).or &&
      (where as OrClause<T>).or.length > 0
    ) {
      where = {
        and: [
          {
            deleted: false,
          } as Condition<T>,
          {
            or: (where as OrClause<T>).or,
          },
        ],
      };
    } else {
      where = where ?? {};
      (where as Condition<T>).deleted = false;
    }

    // Now call super
    return super.count(where, options);
  }

  delete(entity: T, options?: Options): Promise<void> {
    // Do soft delete, no hard delete allowed
    (entity as SoftDeleteEntity).deleted = true;
    (entity as SoftDeleteEntity).deletedOn = new Date();

    return super.update(entity, options);
  }

  deleteAll(where?: Where<T>, options?: Options): Promise<Count> {
    // Do soft delete, no hard delete allowed
    return this.updateAll(
      {
        deleted: true,
        deletedOn: new Date(),
      } as DataObject<T>,
      where,
      options,
    );
  }

  deleteById(id: ID, options?: Options): Promise<void> {
    // Do soft delete, no hard delete allowed
    return super.updateById(
      id,
      {
        deleted: true,
        deletedOn: new Date(),
      } as DataObject<T>,
      options,
    );
  }

  /**
   * Method to perform hard delete of entries. Take caution.
   * @param entity
   * @param options
   */
  deleteHard(entity: T, options?: Options): Promise<void> {
    // Do hard delete
    return super.delete(entity, options);
  }

  /**
   * Method to perform hard delete of entries. Take caution.
   * @param entity
   * @param options
   */
  deleteAllHard(where?: Where<T>, options?: Options): Promise<Count> {
    // Do hard delete
    return super.deleteAll(where, options);
  }

  /**
   * Method to perform hard delete of entries. Take caution.
   * @param entity
   * @param options
   */
  deleteByIdHard(id: ID, options?: Options): Promise<void> {
    // Do hard delete
    return super.deleteById(id, options);
  }

  static getUser(name: string): string {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

Assuming you are using LoopBack's builtin authentication & security layer (see https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-overview.html), the currently logged-in user can be injected using `SecurityBindings.USER`.

The simplest option is to uses [property injection](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Dependency-injection.html#property-injection) as follows:

```
import {SecurityBindings, UserProfile} from '@loopback/security';

export abstract class SoftCrudRepository<
  T extends SoftDeleteEntity,
  ID,
  Relations extends object = {}
> extends DefaultCrudRepository<T, ID, Relations> {

  @inject(SecurityBindings.USER, {optional: true})
  public currentUser?: UserProfile;

  // Your implementation goes here.
}
```

Use `this.currentUser` to access the currently logged user from your repository methods. Just keep in mind the value is set after the class is instantiated (you cannot access it from the constructor) and the current user is `undefined` for anonymous requests.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please upvote my answer and mark it as an accepted solution if it helped you to solve your use case.

Comment: I can't upvote because...Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded,